# Android Studio SVN Keywords

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I have integrated SVN into my Android Studio. Now I want to include the Keywords like SVN Revision, URL, lastChangedDate from the SVN Server. I have changed the properties from the SVN project to include the Keywords. In the comment section I include the Keyword Substitution as described [herein](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) but it doesn't include the Revision etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that you configured SVN to show the keywords correctly. Don't forget to enable `svn:keywords` property. Re-read the documentation, please:

- [SVNBook 1.8 | Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Note that Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA. Therefore IDEA's documentation should also work for Android Studio. Read this help topic:

- [IntelliJ IDEA Help | How to set up the svn:keywords property](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-subversion-properties-for-files-and-directories.html#keyword)